# Find the most active Twitter friends

Tags: twitter, statistics

I want to find out which of my Twitter followed users are most active, or rather most chatty/loud/frequent posters, so that I can reduce the noise in my home feed.

I usually just open my feed, see who's filling the current few screenfuls, check who has the highest "total tweets" score and mute those I don't care about. However the total number doesn't tell much about recent activity, and scanning the home feed is tedious.

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use SocialBearing. Just log in and open the home feed view at https://socialbearing.com/me/home

Click "load older" a few times, until you have a representative sample of your feed (ideally, at least a couple days; the maximum is 7).

On the left side, among the "facets", you can narrow down the selection of tweets (e.g. to exclude replies) and you'll have list of the most active users in your feed, like this:

[image: 2017 SocialBearing home feed facets]

This feed respects your Twitter options, in particular it filters the accounts you've already muted.